# find element by ul li tag in selenium

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

Trying a slightly different avenue to reach the same conclusion as my previous question.  I am unable to automate a click on a tab menu on a website.  I keep getting an "unable to locate element" error.  I tried searching directly by both name and id, but neither attempt actually clicked on the tab (whether I used `click()` or `submit()`). Now I have been trying xpath, but it is failing as well.

the ul xpath is

```
//*[@id="HomeImage"]/div/div/div[1]/div/section/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/ul
```

li xpath is

```
//*[@id="travelPlanTab"]
```

I tried

```
browser.find_element('xpath', "//[@role='tablist']/li[@id='travelPlanTab']").submit()
```

this failed as well.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are any of the elements you are trying to find loaded async? You need to make sure then to search the element after it got loaded, when the document is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Use OR locator

for example
Xpath[@type='' or @name='']